# Where to place downloaded PHP_CodeSniffer?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I want to download and install [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/download)

On the website is mentioned that it can be installed manually. There is not mentioned, where I should place downloaded folder. 
Is there any standard where I should place such PHP scripts from PEAR website?

I have installed PEAR into php but I cannot use "pear install" command ( I don't know why, either). For me it is more simplier solution to download pear manually.

(I am using WIndows 7)

Comment: What happens when you try to `pear install PHP_CodeSniffer`?

Comment: to Phoenix: I am using Windows 7 command line. I get error "pear is not recognized as internal or external error". I am also using MINGW32to execute some commands. In this program i get error "pear command not found".

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the php [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), or put it somewhere in your application. When you include or require the necessary files, you can specify an absolute or relative path to the file.

Example: if your app is at /my/app, consider putting the pear files in /my/app/lib/Pear, then include /my/app/lib/Pear/CodeSniffer.php

Comment: yes, but what I need to know is where I have to place downloaded folder. Should I place it to path-to-my-php/php/PEAR?